# How to inherit from multiple base abstract classes in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I faced a problem how I can create JPA entity which extends **multiple** base abstract classes (without creating additional table). I know there is an annotation `@MappedSuperclass`, but it gives an ability to create only **one** base class as soon as we use `extends` and multiple inheritance is not a Java feature.

For example, I have two bases:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Authored {
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```

and

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Dated {
    private String creationDate;
}
```

I expect that some of my models will extend only `Authored`, some -- only `Dated`, and some -- both.
Though it's only possible to write

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends Authored {
    ...
}
```

or

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends Dated {
    ...
}
```

Some discussions propose to inherit classes in line (e.g. `Authored` and `AuthoredAndDated`) but this seems too dirty, none of this bases logically can't extend another one.

**ADDITION**

I have to note that this style is supported in other frameworks like Django (due to multiple inheritance in python) so it's strange that JPA doesn't support it.

Comment: In Java you cannot "extend" multiple classes. JPA simply persists your classes, and since you cant define such a class ...

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to disappoint you, but there is no other solution than creating `AuthoredAndDated` as you suggested.

We faced in the same issue for our entities and went with the same procedure.

> We have a

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class TimestampedObject {

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

> and a

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class IdObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

}
```

Thus we created a `TimestampedIdObject` for this purpose.

**Edit:**

If you find another suitable solution, it would be great if you could post it here, as we have the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `@Embeddable` / `@Embedded` for goal by replacing inheritance with composition.

First, do not use `@MappedSuperClass`, but use `@Embeddable` instead for your classes you want to share the attributes with:

```
@Embeddable
public class Authored {...}

@Embeddable
public class Dated {...}
```

In the next step your Entity should not inherit from `Authored` or `Dated` but instead get an attribute referencing them:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Embedded
    private Authored authored;

    @Embedded
    private Dated dated;

}
```

If you want to get behaviour out of this, where you can generically access without  those new attributes, you would need to introduce an interface exposing the necessary methods.

For expample if `MyEntity` should be able to provide details on last updates and creation, you would introduce an interface `Authorable` which defines to methods to access the relevant data.

```
public interface Authorable { /* necessary methods */ }
```

`MyEntity` will implement this interface then:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Authorable { 
    /* previous content plus implemented mehtods from interface */ 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's not a bad idea. but firstly it seems not too much far from just adding a simple field in the model and secondly there are some problems with inserting relationships in @Embeddable [JPA wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Relationships)

Comment: Leveraging the combination of interfaces and associations somehow gets you the flavour of multi-inheritance in java, which is simply not available. The problems with relationships do not seem to apply in your example imho.